# Build a MySql query through Codeigniter that gets a price range in multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have a table that shows rooms with 4 different prices like this:

```
+----+--------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| ID | Levels | p1  | p2  | p3  | p4  |
+----+--------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 1  | 5      | 100 | 90  | 200 | 500 |
+----+--------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 2  | 1      | 400 | 300 | 200 | 100 |
+----+--------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 3  | 3      | 80  | 140 | 130 | 210 |
+----+--------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 4  | 3      | 600 | 450 | 90  | 187 |
+----+--------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 5  | 2      | 580 | 300 | 50  | 40  |
+----+--------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

in the front-end, I have a filter that sends parameters to my controller, then to my model, which then gets the information from the database.

The filter lets the user provide different "ranges" as paramaeters. For example, if the user wants rooms with levels from 0 to 2, my controller breaks this into the following:

```
$params['levels_from'] = 0; 
$params['levels_to'] = 2;
```

then sends it to my model method which then builds the query like this:

```
$this->db->select();
$this->db->from("rooms");
if($params['levels_from']){
    $this->db->where("rooms.levels >=", $params['levels_from']);
}

if($params['levels_to'] {
    $this->db->where("rooms.levels <=", $params['levels_to'] 
}

$q = $this->db->get();
return $q->result();
```

This all works well, but what if I want to give the user the ability to select a price range. For example, if they want the following:

***"All rooms on levels 0-3, with prices that range from $10-$200"***

I would like the query to look through my table, through each price in the columns.

I thought of doing it the same way as I did the levels, but it needs to look through p1, p2, p3, and p4 for all the prices, and Im not sure how to do it.

*Constraints*: I cannot modify the table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since they are in their own column you can't really do anything with that but you can filter them out instead of just returning $q->result()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use or between each price column. The query would look something like this.

```
select * from room where 
rooms.levels >= levels_from and rooms.levels <= levels_to and 
((rooms.p1 >= price_from and rooms.p1<= price_to) or 
(rooms.p2 >= price_from and rooms.p2<= price_to) or 
(rooms.p3 >= price_from and rooms.p3<= price_to) or 
(rooms.p4 >= price_from and rooms.p4<= price_to))
```